# Printing a List in reverse in Python

Tags: loops, for-loop, range, palindrome

Hello (this is my first question on the site so apologies if i have not followed an rules) 
Below are two codes (using for loop) that I have written to print reverse of a string input by the user. One code gives me an error and the other works fine. I cannot understand why. Why is the function "range" seem to make the difference? Appreciate if someone can help me understand the logic - many thanks

**Code 1: That gives me error:**

```
string = input('Enter a Word ')
length = len(string)
reverse = []

for i in string:
    x=string [-1-i]
    reverse.append(x)

print (reverse)
```

*Enter a Word Python

---

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
      4 
      5 for i in string:
----> 6     x=string [-1-i]
      7     reverse.append(x)
      8 
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'str'

**Code 2: This works fine**

```
string = input('Enter a Word ')
length = len (string)
reverse = []

for i in range(length):
    x=string [-1-i]
    reverse.append(x)

print (reverse)
```

*Enter a Word Python

['n', 'o', 'h', 't', 'y', 'P']*

Comment: print the value of `i` in each of the loops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `for i in string`, `i` will take the value of each character in the string, e.g. `'H'`, `'e'`, `'l'`, `'l'`, `'o'` if the input was 'Hello'.

When you call `string[-1-i]`, Python is trying to subtract a string from a number, which is why you get the error `unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'str'`.

Comment: Sure but isn’t the other code doing the same thing ?

Comment: @HaseebHaque, no `i` is 0, 1, 2,... when you use range.

Answer (score 1):

The first loop you are doing is creating a foreach loop for your string, therefore your "i" is basically a char. Do you know there is also a function called "reverse()"?

Comment: Thanks no I did not and thanks for pointing it out. But i really want to understand why one code, above, works and the other does not

Comment: can you please explain the difference between the functions reverse() and reversed ()

Comment: does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6810036/whats-better-the-reverse-method-or-the-reversed-built-in-function

Answer (score 0):

You can make a `reverse` function easily -

```
def reverse(word = ""):
  return word if len(word) < 2 else reverse(word[1::]) + word[0]

myword = "bookkeepper"

print(myword+reverse(myword))
# bookkeepperreppeekkoob
```

Comment: Thank you for the input - what i really want to understand is that how come the second code works and the first does. Both follow pretty much the same logic except for the range function. many thanks